# Bash - string doesn't work inside of a for loop

Tags: bash

I want to retrieve the first part of a file name and iterate through a list of files.  File names are paired and I'm trying to run a program on each pair.  This is what they look like:

```
H1T1A-left.fastq.gz
H1T1A-right.fastq.gz
```

I can strip everything after the - to get unique names:

```
for d in *left*; do
    echo $d | cut -d- -f1;
    echo "Mapping $NAME";
done

H1T1A
H1T1B
H1T1C
H1T2A
H1T2B
```

But if I want to load that in to variable "NAME" so I can pass it to a program:

```
for d in *left*; do
    NAME = echo $d | cut -d- -f1;
    echo "Mapping $NAME";
done
```

And I get an error:

```
NAME: command not found
Mapping
NAME: command not found
Mapping
```

I'd like to be able to pass $NAME as part of a filename for each pair:

```
>program "$NAME"-left.file "$NAME"-right.file
```

Comment: Syntax issue, try your code here (https://www.shellcheck.net/) first, make sure your syntax is ok.  Then post here for logic problems. And http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Comment: I want to take $d | cut -d- -f1 and put the result in NAME so I can use the first part of the filename.  Echo isn't the way to do it, so how would that work?

Comment: This doesn't work *outside* a for loop either. Part of building a good [mcve] is testing taking things away / simplifying until the problem stops happening -- if you'd tried taking away the loop, the issue still would have occurred.

Comment: Didn't know about Shellcheck, that's super great

Comment: BTW, you can (and should!) do this without `cut`; ie. `name=${d%%-*}` -- you'll see a very big difference in performance if you run this on a directory with tens or hundreds of files matching `*left*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the whitespaces around the assignment `=`
if you want to store the output of a commnad in some variable, put the command inside `$(yourcommand)`

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for d in *left*; do
        NAME=$(echo $d | cut -d- -f1)
        echo "Mapping $NAME";
    done
```

Comment: `echo "$d"`, not `echo $d`. If `d='left * right'` (which is a perfectly valid filename!), then `echo $d` will have the names of all the files in your current directory, preceded by `left` and succeeded by `right`.

Comment: Also, note [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the section "Answer well-asked questions", particularly the bullet regarding questions which "*have already been asked and answered many times before*".

Comment: Also, it'd be even more efficient to run `NAME=${d%%-*}`, which avoids the performance cost of running a subshell and spinning up the (external, not-part-of-bash) `cut` command.